# XPATH - Find element where child items h3 text has a specific value

Tags: html, xpath

[image]

I need to find the selected DIV using a 'Employment' text for h3 tag.

I can find it using the following XPATH:

```
.//div[table[tbody[tr[td[h3[text() = 'Employment']]]]]]/following-sibling::div[@class = 'pbBody']
```

But this is too big and ugly, what is the good way? something like:

parent::div[h3]following-sibling::div, so without this **[table[tbody[tr[td[**

HTML text:

```html
<div class="listRelatedObject customnotabBlock">
<div class="bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd secondaryPalette">
<div class="pbHeader">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="pbTitle">
<img class="minWidth" width="12" height="1" title="" style="margin-right: 0.25em;" alt="" src="/img/s.gif"/>
<img class="relatedListIcon" title="Custom" alt="Custom" src="/img/s.gif"/>
<h3 id="a1H9E000000528F_00N2400000IF18T_title">Employment</h3>
</td>
<td class="pbButton">
<td class="pbHelp">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="DIV_THAT_I_NEED_TO_FIND" class="pbBody">
<div class="pbFooter secondaryPalette">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide HTML code.

Comment: I did it with a screenshot. Now I can't do it in a comment - it's too long

Comment: you can edit the question to include the html in text format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want shorter version you can try

```
//h3[.="Employment"]/following::div[@class="pbBody"]
```

Comment: it should be `ancestor::` instead of `following::` if you are looking for parent element

Comment: Yep, but OP doesn't look for parent element. Check image with provided `HTML` source

Answer (score 1):

The most simple locator:

```
//div[@class="pbBody"][.//h3[text()='Employment']
```

but better to use "contains", as usually classes could be added to element

```
//div[contains(@class, "pbBody")][.//h3[text()='Employment']
```

And last one is similar to @Andersson 's, but corrected (as you need not following element, but ancestor):

```
//h3[.="Employment"]/ancestor::div[@class="pbBody"]
```